# How to create a rounddown in ms excel with range?

Tags: excel

I just want to ask a question about creating a rounddown formula in excel.
The logic is to generate a rounddown numbers based on the range.

For example:

```
90-99 = 90
80-89 = 80
```

Numbers between 90 to 99 should be 90
And numbers between 80 - 89 should be 80

How can i create a formula for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula :

```
=A1-MOD(A1;10)
```

Here I have subtracted from the cell's value, the rest of the division of your cell's value with 10 (function modulo)

Comment: It depends on your excel's version :)

Comment: ah ok sorry. I am using excel 2007

Comment: It's not the **version** but your **regional settings** - comma is the default separator in UK and US regional settings. Where comma is used as the decimal separator, e.g. France/Germany the semi-colon ; is used as the "argument separator"

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the question......

You can use ROUNDDOWN function, i.e.

`=ROUNDOWN(A1,-1)`

The -1 indicates rounding down to the previous multiple of 10, -2 would give 100, -3 1000 etc.

...or FLOOR function will also work

`=FLOOR(A1,10)`